# How change the color of text when clicking a button using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of button when it's clicked.So I wrote this program.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myprojects_button = document.getElementById("myprojects_button");
  $(myprojects_button).click(function() {
    $("myprojects_text").css("color: #cd1692");
  });
});
```

```css
.myprojects_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myprojects_text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Arial Round MT Bold";
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fa.fa-list-alt {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg {
  background-color: #1b191a;
  border: #1b191a;
  height: 49px;
}

.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:hover,
.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:focus,
.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myprojects_div" class="myprojects_div">
  <button id="myprojects_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#">
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="myprojects_text">My projects<p>
  </button>
</div>
```

But when I clicked on the button, the color doesn't change.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `$(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");` select element using class you have to add `.` before class name

Comment: You missed the `.` in the class selector. Also `.css("color: #cd1692");` should be `.css('color', '#cd1692')` - or better yet, use a class. Closing as a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage of .css() is described [here](https://api.jquery.com/css/)
just change the javascript part to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#myprojects_button").click(function() {
        $(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the dot for the class name, additionally you don't need to get the ID that way::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myprojects_button").click(function(){
   $(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");
 }); 
});
```

Comment: @mayersdesign still something missing ;-)

Comment: n @mayersdesign is acting as if there is no tomorrow.. ;)

Comment: @mayersdesign indeed :)

Comment: I'm freelance... there's no Sunday either! :'(

Answer (score 1):

`$(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");` select element using class you have to add . before class name

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myprojects_button = document.getElementById("myprojects_button");
  $(myprojects_button).click(function(){
      $(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myprojects_div" class="myprojects_div">
 <button id="myprojects_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#">
  <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="myprojects_text">My projects<p>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's your solution -**
Copy the code below into a .html file and open on browser -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

            .myprojects_div {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .myprojects_text {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: "Arial Round MT Bold";
                color: #ffffff;
                line-height: 1.2;
                padding-top: 0px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            .fa.fa-list-alt {
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .btn.btn-primary.btn-lg {
                background-color: #1b191a;
                border: #1b191a;
                height: 49px;
            }

            .btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:hover,
            .btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:focus,
            .btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:active {
                box-shadow: none;
                color: #8e8e8e;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="myprojects_div" class="myprojects_div">
            <button id="myprojects_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#">
                <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="myprojects_text">
                    My projects
                <p>
            </button>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var myprojects_button = document.getElementById("myprojects_button");
                $(myprojects_button).click(function(){
                    $(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");
                });
            }); 
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

check syntax properly in jquery.
Only change your script . you are missing . for class and also your .css() is also wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myprojects_button").click(function() {
    $(".myprojects_text").css("color","#cd1692");
  });
});
```

```css
.myprojects_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myprojects_text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Arial Round MT Bold";
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fa.fa-list-alt {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg {
  background-color: #1b191a;
  border: #1b191a;
  height: 49px;
}

.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:hover,
.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:focus,
.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myprojects_div" class="myprojects_div">
  <button id="myprojects_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#">
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="myprojects_text">My projects<p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change text color

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myprojects_button").click(function(){
        $(this).find("p").css('color', '#cd1692'); 
        // Or change background-color
        $(this).css('background-color', '#cd1692');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

apply this approach to your code it may help you.

-- Script Section

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(".hey").css("background-color","red");
});
});
</script>
```

-- HTML Section

```
 <body>
  <p class="hey">Hello</p>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="click"/>
  </body>
```